# Change the type of an object through a method call without returning a new instance

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

Recently I stumbled upon a problem about object oriented design.

A little bit about the background:
I decided to create a good old todo-app to learn a bit more about 
PHPUnit and testable PHP in general. Requirements were the usual
retrieve/store/edit tasks. The todos should be stored in a MySQL
database.

My idea was to create a base class `Todo`, which holds a PDO instance
as well as the id and title of the todo (equivalent to their
representation in the database).

Additionally it should have two factory methods responsible for
creating instances of different todos. These are:

1. New todos defined with the frontend of the app
2. Already saved todos.

The reason for this is the different behaviour of storing the
current state (the title/description) in the database.

My first attempt without subclasses looked something like this:

```
class Todo {
    [...] // fields and other methods

    public function save() {
        $statement = '';
        $parameters = [];

        if (is_null($this->_id)) {
            $statement = 'insert into todos (title) values(?)';
            $parameters = [$this->_title];
        } else {
            $statement = 'update todos set title = ? where id = ?';
            $parameters = [$this->_title, $this->_id];
        }

        $prepared_statement = $this->_pdo->prepare($statement);
        $result = $prepared_statement->execute($parameters);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

The if statement revealed that I basically just checked for the type of 
the todo. In other words: Is the todo a new todo that I want
to store with an insert-statement, or is the todo already in
the database so that I have to treat it with an update-statement.

To get rid of the if statement I introduced the subclasses `NewTodo` and `SavedTodo`.
Eventually I ended up with the following:

```
abstract class Todo {
    [...] // fields and other methods

    public abstract function save();
}

class NewTodo extends Todo {
    public function save() {
        $statement = 'insert into todos (title) values(?)';
        $parameters = [$this->getTitle()];

        $prepared_statement = $this->getPdo()->prepare($statement);
        $result = $prepared_statement->execute($parameters);

        return $result;
    }
}

class SavedTodo extends Todo {
    public function save() {
        $statement = 'update todos set title = ? where id = ?';

        $parameters = [
            $this->getTitle(),
            $this->getId()
        ];

        $prepared_statement = $this->getPdo()->prepare($statement);
        $result = $prepared_statement->execute($parameters);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Although this seems way more reasonable to me, I'm now facing the actual
problem with this approach.

> I - in a naive way - would expect an instance of `NewTodo` that calls
>   the `save()` method to be an instance of `SavedTodo` afterwards.

Obviously this is not the case in my implementation.

After this "wall of introduction", finally my questions:

> Is there any way to implement this in PHP **without returning a new instance**?

And maybe more important:

> Is it **reasonable** to have this kind of behaviour implemented at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think trying to represent an objects state through its type is a good idea. As you have pointed out, what do you do when its saved, and it then should be a `SavedTodo`. Even if you implemented that, it would be a strange structure to work with. For example:

```
$t = new NewTodo();
$t->content = 'testing';
$savedTodo = $t->save();
$t = $savedTodo; // need to overwrite the original Todo with the SavedTodo
```

As you can see, it's not what you want expect to have to do, if you were to look at the code from an outsiders perspective.

The if statement in your first case is not a problem that needs solving. In OOP, inheritance is a feature, not a requirement so if it doesn't fit the job, don't use it.

---

A good rule of thumb in OOP is to loosley follow [SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which is basically to have clear roles for your classes where they aren't doing too much. Ideally they should have a single responsibility.

Personally I wouldn't put the save method on the Todo because it is an entity, whose responsibility is to represent a Todo in the system. Giving a Todo the ability to save itself could be considered another responsibilty, so I would prefer to have a TodoMapper class that deals with fetching, inserting, updating and deleting.

Also, the Todo entity in the system shouldn't be concerned about what method of data storage the system uses, or what type of database etc etc, or even if gets stored at all.

For example:

```
$todoMapper = new TodoMapper($pdo);

$todo = new Todo();
$todo->content = 'testing';

$todoMapper->save($todo);
```

In this system, the mapper can check if the Todo has an ID or not, and do an UPDATE or INSERT accordingly. Or if you prefer, you can have `insert()` and `update()` methods on the mapper class.
Another benefit of this design is the Todo doesn't need the PDO object because it doesn't concern itself with CRUD operations.

Martin Fowler has more information on [Data Mapper classes here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Your first example shows exactly what I tried to avoid. The question about an object changing its type without actually **assigning** a new one just came up while programming.